# Create Classification Tree in R

Tags: r

I have the following simple data set:

```
x1 = as.data.frame(as.integer(runif(10, 1,3)))
colnames(x1)[1] <- 'var'
x1$label = "a"

x2 = as.data.frame(as.integer(runif(10, 1, 3)))
colnames(x2)[1] <- 'var'
x2$label = "b"

X = rbind(x1, x2)
```

and I am suppose to create a classification tree without using the built-in tree functions in R. So far I have calculated the entropy for each of the features as follows:

```
  no_label_1 <- sum(X$label=="a")
  no_label_2 <- sum(X$label=="b")

  p_class_1 <- no_label_1/length(X$class)
  p_class_2 <- no_label_2/length(X$class)

  entropy <-  (p_class_1*log2(p_class_1)+p_class_2*log2(p_class_2))

  no_x_1 <- sum(X$var==1)
  no_x_2 <- sum(X$var==2)

  p_x_1 <- no_x_1/length(X$var)
  p_x_2 <- no_x_2/length(X$var)

  entropy_x <- -(p_x_1*log2(p_x_1)+p_x_2*log2(p_x_2))
```

as this is a simple example the tree would only have to split once and we would arrive at the desired result but if there were more features we would have to wrap this into a functions such that:

```
create function tree{
if entropy < desired value
   create split
for each split
   find the variable that is associate with the split
}

create function split{
   for all possible splits
   split on variable which has the highest entropy
return best variable for split
}
```

I am trying to get the functions set up to create this tree but I do not know how to set this up properly. Any help on how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Show your attempt

Comment: Do some basic research into how functions work in R, post your attempt, and then we can help you out if you're still struggling.